# How to store downloads folder on our private repo in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

After a successful "bitbake core-image-sato" build, i moved the downloads folder to my private repository, and then deleted downloads the folder and fetched it from my private repository.

I added BB_NO_NETWORK = "1" in local.conf, and when I tried to do "bitbake core-image-sato" it fails.

```
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: gnu-config-native-20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0 do_fetch: Network access disabled through BB_NO_NETWORK (or set indirectly due to use of BB_FETCH_PREMIRRORONLY) but access requested with command LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 fetch -f --prune --progress git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git refs/*:refs/* (for url git://git.savannah.gnu.org/config.git)
ERROR: gnu-config-native-20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/jamal/test/new_repot/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20150728+gitAUTOINC+b576fa87c1-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.29816
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/jamal/test/new_repot/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

It is trying to fetch the source code again, from network, as network access is disabled it fails.

Can you guys please help me in resolving this problem. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Did you also set `BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"` in `local.conf` during the first download? Otherwise a tarballs from git repositories are not created.

Comment: No, I did not.. Do we need to also add SOURCE_MIRROR_URL

Comment: I'm not sure. I have it in my `local.conf` (along with `INHERIT += "own-mirrors"`), but we have a download server so I'm downloading from it. Your use case looks a bit different - you have everything on one machine, so the correct `DL_DIR` might be sufficient.

Comment: Can we push downloads folder to our private repo directly or do we need to make any changes in local.conf for pushing downloads to local repo

Comment: I think that you can reuse (i.e. copy) the content of the first DL_DIR as is to your repo (don't forget to set `BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"` to make tarballs of scm repositories). The correct `DL_DIR` in your `local.conf` for the second build should be sufficient. Please test and let us know the result.

Comment: Hi, its successful. You can post it as answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is missing `BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"` in `local.conf`. Tarballs from git repositories are automatically not created due to performance reasons, see the [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS). Setting that variable enables creating of the tarballs, so they can be used later on and git server don't need to be contacted.

(Please see comments for the question for more information, we discussed the solution there. Thanks to @md.jamal for testing it.)